# Search XML webpage for string

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to search the following XML code for the `id="1140"` and return the child objects after the id. Below is a sample of the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<location france="paris">
    <loc name="tower" id="1140">
        <visit date="17.06.2013" time="12:00">
        <visit status="set" date="17.06.2013" time="12:00" loc="Court" id="6711709">
        <visit name="A. Hill" male="True" paid="40" confirmed="1" id="1627" />
        <visit name="D. Hill" male="False" paid="40" confirmed="1" id="1627" />
    </data>
```

This is not an HTML document, it's an XML webpage. Would anyone know the best way to extract the data I require?

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML parser. For instance, [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a good option. Whatever you do, don't try to extract the information by directly manipulating the string or using regular expressions - that will be a lot of trouble, and parsers were designed for this, they're the right tool for this job.